# How do i prove that the set of all $Q$-box is a semi ring?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the uniqueness of the lesbesgue measure.

Typically, there are two distinct ways to construct the lebesgue measure. One is via outer measure and one is via completion of borel sets.

By $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, it is *relatively easy* to prove that any translational-invariant measures on borel algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the value $\mu([0,1]^n)=1$ are mutiple of each other.

What i want to prove is that "Restriction of the Lebesgue outer measure on the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets" is actually the completion of some translational-invariant measure with the value $\mu([0,1]^n)=1$.

Indeed, if i can prove that the set of every $Q$-box is semi-ring, the proof is done.

Let $S=\{(a,b]|a<b\}$. Then $S$ is closed under intersection and relative complement.

Now, define $Q=\{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i] : (a_i,b_i] \in S\}$.

It is clear that " $\forall A,B\in Q$, there exists a finite sequence in $Q$ whose union is $A\setminus B$" .

I tried to draw a diagram several times, but i could not find a case where $A\setminus B$ is *not a disjoint union* of finite elements in $Q$.

How do i prove that $Q$ is a semi-ring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Do it for $n=1,2$ by drawing pictures and then generalize. Alternatively, do a similar exercise for $\{1,\ldots,k\}^n$ and notice that it follows that it holds for certain class of finitely generated $Q_0\leq Q$ and hence for $Q$ as well.